# open-source mini-heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, sinatra, rack

I started playing with Sinatra and deploying on Heroku, which I find really enjoyable. I don't need the scalability Heroku provides, but I really like their CLI and the ability to deploy an app with a simple push. Is there an open source project that releases a VM image that I could slap say, on an EC2 instance and that would provide the same services (web server, postgres, git push-to-deploy, maintenance mode...) 'in the small'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [CloudFoundry](http://cloudfoundry.org).  They're releasing their platform as open source.

Comment: Just found out about [Nodester](http://nodester.com/) which is also FOSS but limited to node.js

Comment: Is there any other alternative? Nodester uses chroot, which sucks for production.

Comment: @vinnylinux: Why? Chroots are amongst the most popular security measures for production servers. OpenBSD even uses them extensively for daemons in the base system.

Answer (score 22):

Dokku was released recently (https://github.com/progrium/dokku/):

> Docker powered mini-Heroku. The smallest PaaS implementation you've ever seen.
>   Assumes Ubuntu 13 right now. Ideally have a domain ready to point to your host. It's designed for and is probably best to use a fresh VM. The bootstrapper will install everything it needs.

- Docker - Container runtime and manager
- Buildstep - Buildpack builder
- gitreceive - Git push interface
- sshcommand - Fixed commands over SSH

*Update Feb 2014: also have a look at [Flynn](https://flynn.io) especially if you need multitenancy or a multi-host setup.

The author of Dokku is actively involved in the development of Flynn.*

Comment: Being Docker-powered, it's linux-only. :(

Comment: > Being Docker-powered, it's linux-only. :( 
The OP asked for a solution that can be "slapped on a VM" so this is not an issue.
Check out [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/) and possible https://github.com/neam/vagrant-docker-local-dev-vm for using docker locally.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/neam/dokku-host-provisioning for provisioning a cloud instance with Dokku) for "slapping" Dokku onto any server accessible with ssh :)

Comment: Docker also works on freebsd, so in theory you can make it work there as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option seems to be [OpenRuku](https://github.com/openruko), an "in-development MIT licensed open-source Heroku clone/implementation."

They have a [vagrant template](https://github.com/openruko/vagrant-openruko) you can use to create a fully running OpenRuku VM.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) from Red Hat.

It is open source and very well developed. You can try use it on their servers and later install all the system on your own dedicated servers.

Answer (score -3):

Heroku is OSS: https://github.com/heroku

Could you use that to deploy your own heroku client?

**edit**

Just realized you asked for a VM, which isn't quite what i answered...

Comment: Thanks for the link, but from what I can see they only open-source client-side code, plus a few deployment-related packages? Turning this into a debian package or VM image would require quite a lot of elbow grease, I suppose...

Comment: Ive uploaded some packages that can be used to complete the server-side part of heroku stack, under MIT - openruko, still a WIP and missing the front-end routing, but might be interest to those wanting to build/experiment with their own mini-heroku https://github.com/nonuby

Comment: @Jim those are only pieces - they haven't open-sourced their entire stack.